# iOS: How do I allow scrolling only when the user drags the scrollbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have been trying to create a scrollable view using UIScrollView. I want this view to be a scratchpad where I can do rough work with touch gestures.
But, doing a drag gesture makes the UIScrollView move the page.
This is why I want to disable scrolling on gesture and enable scrolling only when I drag the scroll bars on the screen.
I have tried Googling, but haven't found any result so far.

It would be great if you could guide me to a solution or help me with some pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you can or that it would be usable.

How about enabling scrolling only with 2 fingers? By setting the scroll view pan gesture `minimumNumberOfTouches` To 2.

Otherwise, think about acting as the delegate of the scroll view pan gesture, specifically for `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` so that you can examine the touch position and only allow the gesture to start of significantly close to the edge of the view.

Comment: Thanks Wain. I had thought about that approach, but it was not a feasible option for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I world recommend using this library: https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

1- Use instance method to add the scrollBar
2- in your UIViewController add these lines of code

```
// First intit by using the instance method 
_brScrollBarController = [BRScrollBarController initForScrollView:self.scrollView
                                                       inPosition:kIntBRScrollBarPositionRight
                                                         delegate:self];
// show the scrollBar always, do not hide
_brScrollBarController.scrollBar.hideScrollBar = NO;
// disable scrolling for your scrollView
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

3- now your scrollView will not respond to gestures, and you will use `BRScrollView` to scroll by dragging the bar

let me know if you have any questions